# mysql php dynamic sql query

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

Edit: Editing my question as the question has changed since originally posted.

As per Rajesh's suggesstion. I have now modified  the php code.

Here is the new code, but it still does not work.

Basically I want to run the same query several times but each time it will be group by different column.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    try {
        $objDatabase = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
        $objDatabase->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>

<?php 

//Process the GET data received from the previous page.
$custo = $_GET["Customer"];
$startdate = $_GET["fromdate"];
$enddate = $_GET["enddate"];
$stdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startdate));
$endate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($enddate));


$basequery = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, method, date, stime, etime, wks, result, COUNT(*) AS total FROM hdds WHERE cust = '".$custo."' and `date` >= '".$stdate."' and `date` <= '".$endate."'";

$retval = mysql_query( $basequery, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>


<? php 

$type="capacity";
$typeQuery = $basequery." GROUP BY ".$type;
// Perform the Query
$objDbResultByType = $objDatabase->Query($typeQuery);
echo '<div id="1000" style="display: none;">';
echo "<h3>Quality Control Checked by<br></h3><strong>";
$capacity = array();
while ($row = $objDbResultByType->FetchArray()) {
    echo $row['capacity']. " = " .$row['total'];
    echo "<br><strong>";
$result = "{ label: \"".$row['capacity']."\", y: " .$row['total']." },";
array_push($capacity,$result);
}
//echo $result;
$lastIndex = count($capacity)-1;
$lastValue = $capacity[$lastIndex];
$testedby[$lastIndex] = rtrim($lastValue, ',');

//Echo the capacity from array to the monitor screen. 
foreach ($capacity as $result){
echo $result, '<br>';
}

?>
```

This code still does not work. It gives me a blank screen.

However if I run this query on mysql it returns the data, there is no problem with the query.

```
mysql> SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, method, date, stime, etime, wks, result, COUNT(*) AS total from hdds where cust = 'Imran-ABC' and date >= '2015-08-01' and '2015-09-14' group by date;
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------+
| cust      | manu                                     | model      | serial   | capacity                    | firmware | method | date       | stime    | etime    | wks  | result    | total |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------+
| ABC | Seagate Barracuda 7200.7 and 7200.7 Plus | ST340014AS | 5MQ3DJPM | 40000000000 bytes [40.0 GB] | 8.12     | zero   | 2015-08-26 | 18:56:29 | 18:56:29 | 89   | Succeeded |     1 |
| ABC | Seagate Barracuda 7200.7 and 7200.7 Plus | ST340014AS | 5MQ3DJPM | 40000000000 bytes [40.0 GB] | 8.12     | zero   | 2015-09-01 | 18:56:29 | 18:56:29 | 89   | Succeeded |    27 |
| ABC | Seagate Barracuda 7200.7 and 7200.7 Plus | ST340014AS | 5MQ3DJPM | 40000000000 bytes [40.0 GB] | 8.12     | zero   | 2015-09-02 | 20:04:19 | 20:04:19 | 36   | Succeeded |     2 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks well in advance.

Comment: Where is `$objDatabase` defined?

Comment: @Rajeshkannan There's no need to post a comment about your own answer.

Comment: What is $baseQuery over here : $typeQuery = getQueryGroupBy($baseQuery, 'capacity');

Comment: $objDatabase is not defined anywhere I guess, hence I am having problem. Can you help me fix this,

Comment: If you don't know what $objDatabase is how should we? My guess is you just copied&pasted some other script fragments without understanding what they do?

Comment: VolkerK, you are right, I copied and pasted the segment from another page hoping that it will work. $objDatabase is not defined anywhere. As explained I just want the query to work with "Group By" dynamically

Comment: This is an incredibly vague question title.  Please make the title more specific/searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `$objDatabase` like in the following

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "your_username";
    $password = "your_password";

    try {
        $objDatabase = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
        $objDatabase->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

use the query string below

```
$basequery = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, method, date, stime, etime, wks, result, COUNT(*) AS total FROM hdds WHERE cust = '".$custo."' and `date` >= '".$stdate."' and `date` <= '".$endate."'";
```

And you can get the `$typeQuery` like in the below

```
$type="capacity";
$typeQuery = $basequery." GROUP BY ".$type;
```

give a try

Use `foreach` to fetch the result instead of `while`

```
$objDbResultByType = $objDatabase->query($typeQuery);

foreach ($objDbResultByType as $row) {
/*your code here*/
}
```

let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Actually I have done the following changes

1) added single quote before and after the php variable and done string concatination using `(.)` operator
2) Added `backtick` for `date` variable as it is reserve word (may be it is causing the issue)
3) and added `date<=$enddate ` condition

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this query, I am using this query in another page and it works fine, If you read the php part below, you will understand that I want to run this query dynamically group by " " the group by word will be unique, this is to avoid writing the entire query. I hope you understood

Comment: @Rajeshkannan Put that in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: `date` is not a reserved word. Someone else posted that, he has already deleted his answer.

Comment: @user2107349 i have edited my answer as you said you want to do in using group by clause. Instead of calling a seperate function you can do the concatination opertation in the current function iteself

Comment: $objDtabase->Query is not defined anywhere thats why I am having problems probably. Can you help me write the php part from scratch it may help? Thanks

Comment: @user2107349 Sure. I have Edited my answer check now

Comment: Rajesh, I have updated my question now with your code, it still does not work. There is more information available that may help to answer the question

Comment: Updated answer.. included the fetching part. use `foreach` as in my answer and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Rajesh you are a star, this now works as it should. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the dates. And you should be using `BETWEEN`, not `>=`, to test if the date is between the start and end dates.

You also need a space after `AS total`; otherwise, the query ends up being `COUNT(*) AS totalFROM hdds`, which is causing your syntax error.

```
$basequery = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, method, date, stime, etime, wks, result, COUNT(*) AS total ".
   "FROM hdds ".
   "WHERE cust = '$custo' and date BETWEEN '$stdate' AND '$endate' ";
```

There's really no need to end the string on each line. PHP allows you to have line breaks in strings, so you can just continue the string across all the lines:

```
$basequery = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, method, date, stime, etime, wks, result, COUNT(*) AS total
   FROM hdds
   WHERE cust = '$custo' and date BETWEEN '$stdate' AND '$endate' ";
```

Comment: I'm going to ignore that and assume it's in code he didn't bother to include in the question.

Comment: Basically I copied the php part that contains $objDatabase hence it is not working. Could you help me write the php so that I can run this query "Group by" dynamically.

Comment: You have a typo: `getQueryGroupBy($baseQuery, 'capacity');` should be `getQueryGroupBy($basequery, 'capacity');`. The `Q` should be `q`.

Comment: And just use `mysql_query()` instead of `$objDatabase->query()`. Why do you copy code without understanding what it's doing? That depends on using a database class that you're not loading.